# Find documents, do some business logic and remove using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if the following code will work, if not can anyone please provide an alternative?

```
db.model('orders').find({creationDate: {$lt:today}}, {status: "Active"}).exec(function(err,orders){
        if(err) ...
        if(orders){
            for(var i = 0 ; i < orders.length ; i++){
                //  some business logic here....
                orders[i].remove(function(err){
                    if(err) ...
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

My goal is to query for some documents based on `creationDate` and `status` and then do some business logic based on those documents. Once i finished with the Business Logic, i want to Edit those docs and save them to the DB.

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier and intuitive way would be to use the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** libary. Use the **[`async.series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** method when you need to run multiple tasks that depends on each other and when they all finish do something else.

Consider the following example:

```
// Define query document out here, so both tasks can access it
var query = {"creationDate": {"$lt": today}}, {"status": "Active"};     
async.series([
    // Load orders that satisfy the above query to do the business logic first
    function(callback) {
        db.model('orders').find(query).exec(function(err, orders) {
            if (err) return callback(err); 
            // Do the business logic here
            ....

            callback();
        });
    },

    // Update orders (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" has been called)
    function(callback) {
        db.model('orders').update(
            query, 
            {"$set": {"status": "Deleted"}},
            {"multi": true}
        ).exec(function(err, results) {
            if (err) return callback(err);              
            callback();
        });
    }
], function(err) { 
    // This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
    if (err) return next(err);
    // Do something else after the two tasks have been called
});
```

Comment: Elegant solution, however i do not have that many business logic to do here, its very simple task. BTW, i have changed my requirement from wanting to delete the `order` object to just update its `status` field to `Deleted`

Comment: @TBE I've updated the answer though it's considered bad practice here on SO to change the requirements as you have done because it is very misleading to other users who come along and see that answers provided do not match what you have asked. Nonetheless, it doesn't matter how much business logic you need to do within a task, the concept here is to use the async library for handling nested asynchronous callbacks in a more graceful and readable way, as depicted in the answer above.

Comment: i have updated my question accordingly. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Can you please explain what the `callback()` is for? It is called from inside the mongoose's `callback` function

Comment: Best explained in the [**docs**](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) what those callbacks are for but basically all the async functions take a set of tasks to perform as argument. Each task is given a callback function which must be called when the task is completed, e.g. after an asynchronous call to the database has completed. The async functions also take a callback function as argument, let's call this the final callback. The final callback is called when all tasks have completed, i.e. called their respective task callback functions.

Comment: @chridam Wouldn't it be better (and easier) to pluck all the _id's and perform a multi update? That would definitely lower the database operations.

Comment: @ThomasBormans I agree performance could be improved and can be faster using bulk API but then again that depends on the collection size.